# Filtering out data React Native best practice

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I need advice on where to perform data filtering to achieve best performance. Let's say I receive a big array of **products** from one endpoint of a remote API and **product categories** from another endpoint. I store them in `Redux` state and also persist to `Realm` database so that they are available for offline usage.

In my app, I have a `Stack.Navigator` that contains 2 screens: `ProductCategories` and `ProductsList`. When you press on a **category** it brings you to the screen with **products** that fall under that **category**. Currently, I perform the data filtering right inside my component, from my understanding it fires off every time the component is rendered and I suspect this approach slows down the app.
So I was wondering if there is a better way of doing that? Maybe filter the data for each **category** in advance when the app is loading?

My code looks as follows:

```
const ProductCategories = (props) => {

const isFocused = useIsFocused();

useEffect(() => {
    if (isFocused) {
      setItems(props.productCategories);
    } 
  }, [isFocused]);

return ( 
 ...
 );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  productCategories: state.catalog.productCategories,
});
```

```
const ProductsList = (props) => {

const isFocused = useIsFocused();

const productsFilteredByCategory = props.products.filter((product) => {
    return product.category === id;
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFocused) {
      setItems(productsFilteredByCategory);
    } 
  }, [isFocused]);

return (
...
)


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  products: state.catalog.products,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to normalize (you can see main principles [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalizr)) data in redux, to the next view:

```js
// redux store
{
  categories: {
    1: { // id of category
      id: 1,
      title: 'some',
      products: [1, 2, 3] // ids of products
    },
    ...
  },
  products: {
    1: { // id of product
      id: 1,
      title: 'some product',
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

Then you can create few selectors which will be even without memoization work much faster then filter, because time of taking data from object by property is constant

```js
const getCategory = (state, categoryId) => state.categories[categoryId]
const getProduct = (state, productId) => state.products[productId]

const getCategoryProducts = (state, categoryId) => {
  const category = getCategory(state, categoryId);

  if (!category) return [];

  return category.products.map((productId) => getProduct(state, productId))
}
```